# Using `enumerate(arr)` like function to return array of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

Lack of Python know-how. I'm aware of how easy this is with a `for` loop but I'm curious about the capabilities of python.

I have two parallel arrays that have comparable strings. I would like to enumerate over the first string so I can save the indexes, then I can use it to compare. However, I also need to perform a lambda function on the resulting array using both arguments.

```
filter(lambda x,y: y == arr2[x], list(enumerate(arr1))
```

The lambda function fails because enumerate returns a list of tuples, and the lambda function interprets them as single arguments.

is there an inline alternative to `enumerate` that would give me the result I want? (array of arrays)

**current output:** `[(0,value),(1,value),(2,value)...]`

**desired output:** `[[0,value],[1,value],[2,value]...]`

Comment: Please explain what the expected output is with two sample lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with the `zip` function. [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function doc.

```py
arr1 = [1, 2, 4]
arr2 = [1, 3, 4]
filter(lambda p: p[0] == p[1], [pair for pair in zip(arr1, arr2)])
```

`zip` returns iterable of pairs that contains values of elements with the same indexes.

Update: yes, the solution may be simplified

```
filter(lambda p: p[0] == p[1], zip(arr1, arr2))
```

Comment: Instead of `[pair for pair in zip(arr1, arr2)]`, just `zip(arr1, arr2)` suffices.

Comment: @Tomothy32 yes, sure

Comment: I just realized that my issue was not in the function I used, but rather my lambda syntax. `enumerate` gives me a workable result. `zip` does make things more simple.